# Kafka streams DSL Header support

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I can check the header support in Processor API using processor context.
I need to decide the streams to push records based on header.
How can we do the same in DSL?

Comment: Using `KStream#to(TopicNameExtractor)` you get access to the record header, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing headers (which are part of the message metadata) isn't possible through DSL directly. 
As you said it's possible to access them using the Processor API (since 2.0 version).
Currently the only way you have for accessing headers in DSL is using DSL methods like `transform()` or `transformValues()` so actually using Processor API inside them.
There is a work in progress KIP for addressing this lack: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-159%3A+Introducing+Rich+functions+to+Streams

Comment: Using `KStream#to(TopicNameExtractor)` you get access to the record header, too.